# Android ContentProvider and ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to use overrided applyBatch() method on a custom contentprovider. I know it gets passed an ArrayList of ContentProviderOperations. In my case they're all update ContentProviderOperations. In my provider I want to update the data in a simple array (my stand-in DB for now) that was at first inserted into the ContentProviderOperation.Builder.

The important code bits so far:

Where I build my ContentProviderOperations with my data from the channels array:

```
public void setNumValues(Uri mindex, int[] channels)
        {//setting type to 0 first for everything
            //first is RPM, then Speed
            ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[channels.length];        
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        for (int i = 0; i< channels.length-1; i++){
            values[i].put(NumberProvider.numColumnNames[NumberProvider.VALUE], channels[i]);
            values[i].put(NumberProvider.numColumnNames[NumberProvider.TYPE], 0);

        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(NumberProvider.NUM_PROVIDER_MODEL_URI).withValues(values[i]).build());
        }
        //values.put(NumberProvider.numColumnNames[NumberProvider.VALUE], value);   
        //mContext.getContentResolver().update(mindex, values, null,null);
        try {
            mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(NumberProvider.NUM_AUTHORITY,operations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then my overridden methods in my provider:

```
@Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        int tableindex = (int) (ContentUris.parseId(uri));

    if ((tableindex > 0) && (tableindex <= numProviderDataList.size())) {
        numProviderDataType Data = numProviderDataList.get(tableindex - 1);

        Data.value = values.getAsInteger(numColumnNames[VALUE]);


        // Log.e("Provider1", Float.toString(Data.mValue1));
        // Log.e("Provider2", Float.toString(Data.mValue2));
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    return 1;
}

@Override
public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops)
        throws OperationApplicationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentProviderResult[] result;
    try{
    result = super.applyBatch(ops); //Does this call my provider's update() method?

    } catch(OperationApplicationException e){
        throw e;
    }
    //let observer know there's been a change at the URI
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(NUM_PROVIDER_MODEL_URI, null);
    return result;
```

How do I then get the data out of the ops ArrayList so I can put it in my storage structure? In this case it's a simple array. Does super.applyBatch() in the overrided applyBatch() recognize that they're all update ContentProviderOperations and then calls the overrided update method of my provider for ContentProviderOperation in my ops ArrayList? I couldn't find any examples using a custom provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `applyBatch` will iterate of the `ContentProviderOperation` array and call apply on each one, which in turn will call your provider's `insert`, `update` or `delete` methods.

So yes it will by default call your overridden methods.

There doesn't seem to be able to extract data from a `ContentProviderOperation`, only to call apply to it. Overriding the `applyBatch` should only be used to filter or order operations. Other than that you should just rely on your `insert`, `update` or `delete` implementations.